# Form Alter Foreach Loop changes not sticking

Tags: theming, views, forms

I'm trying to modify my exposed filter block to put each of the controls inside fieldsets, and make other modifications to them.

However, when I try to utilize a foreach loop to do this, none of my changes are 'sticking'.

```
foreach($form_state['input'] as $delta => $input) { 
    $collapsed = (empty($input) ? TRUE : FALSE);

    $form[$delta . '_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t($form['#info']['filter-' . $delta]['label']),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => $collapsed,
    );

    $form[$delta . '_fieldset'][$delta] = $form[$delta];
    unset($form[$delta]);
    unset($form['#info']['filter-' . $delta]);

}
```

This wont work, but this will:

```
$delta = 'field_resource_type_tid';
$collapsed = (empty($form_state[$input][$delta]) ? TRUE : FALSE);

$form[$delta . '_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t($form['#info']['filter-' . $delta]['label']),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => $collapsed,
);

$form[$delta . '_fieldset'][$delta] = $form[$delta];
unset($form[$delta]);
unset($form['#info']['filter-' . $delta]);
```

I've been trying to find out why this wont work, but I can't for the life of my figure out what the form modifications wont stick when done inside this foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to resolve my issue, but I'm not sure why. I decided to change what array I was using to iterate through the filter fields on my form. By switching to iterating through the form array instead of form_state, any changes I make to it now are sticking.

```
foreach($form['#info'] as $delta => $input) {
    $filtername = $input['value'];
    $collapsed = (empty($form_state['input'][$filtername]) ? TRUE : FALSE);

    $form[$filtername . '_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t($form['#info']['filter-' . $filtername]['label']),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => $collapsed,
    );

    $form[$filtername . '_fieldset']['' . $filtername] = $form[$filtername];
    unset($form[$filtername]);
    unset($form['#info']['filter-' . $filtername]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing the $vars by reference by prefixing with "&":

```
foreach(&$form_state['input'] as $delta => $input)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that just tosses a syntax error. Additionally, if I try to pass the $input as byref it doesn't change the output.